# Can't queue jobs using NodeJS async

Tags: javascript, node.js, jobs, child-process

I followed [this tutorial](http://contourline.wordpress.com/2013/10/08/700/), the [async documentation](https://github.com/caolan/async#queueworker-concurrency) and came up with this code.

```
// ASYNC JOBS
var async             = require('async'),
    spawn             = require('child_process').spawn
    maxjobs           = 4;

function setup_R_job(opts,done)
{
  log('starting '+opts.params.pop());
  var params = opts.params;
  delete opts['params'];
  var R = spawn('phantomjs', params, opts);
  R.on('exit',function(code)
  {
    log('got exit code: '+code)
    return null;
  })
  return null;
}
var course_queue=async.queue(setup_R_job, maxjobs);
```

I instantiate the jobs using this function.

```
//instaciante jobs
var jobForCourses = function(urls)
{
  for (var i = urls.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var opts = {  cwd: __dirname,
                  env: process.env,
                  params: ['../getCourseLinks.js','--course']
               };
    opts.params.push(urls[i]);
    log("queueing: "+opts.params.join(' '));
    course_queue.push(opts);
  };
};
```

`jobForCourses` is called as the following.

```
var urls = [url1, url2, url3, url4, url5, url6];
jobForCourses(urls);
```

It should create a job for each of the urls, and execute 4 jobs at a time. When a job is done, it should start the next one. And so on until there is no more jobs in the queue.
At least that's what tell the [async documentation](https://github.com/caolan/async#queueworker-concurrency) about it:

> ## queue(worker, concurrency)
>
> Creates a queue object with the specified concurrency. Tasks added to
>   the queue are processed in parallel (up to the concurrency limit). If
>   all workers are in progress, the task is queued until one becomes
>   available. Once a worker completes a task, that task's callback is
>   called.

However, it starts the 4 first jobs, finish them, and do not instantiate the others.
Of course if I set `maxjobs` to `50`, it will execute all of them, but this is not what I want.

## EDIT

if it can help understand, I get the following output:

```
queueing: ../getCourseLinks.js --course /courses/url1
queueing: ../getCourseLinks.js --course /courses/url2
queueing: ../getCourseLinks.js --course /courses/url3
queueing: ../getCourseLinks.js --course /courses/url4
queueing: ../getCourseLinks.js --course /courses/url5
queueing: ../getCourseLinks.js --course /courses/url6
queueing: ../getCourseLinks.js --course /courses/url7
queueing: ../getCourseLinks.js --course /courses/url8
queueing: ../getCourseLinks.js --course /courses/url9
...
starting /courses/url1
starting /courses/url2
starting /courses/url3
starting /courses/url4
got exit code: 0
got exit code: 0
got exit code: 0
got exit code: 0
```

Comment: Is there some particular reason why you are not treating `getCourseLinks` as a regular Node module?

Comment: `getCourseLinks ` is a `phantomjs` script. It can't be executed using Node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to invoke `done` after a process has finished. Try this:

```
function setup_R_job(opts,done) {
  log('starting '+opts.params.pop());
  var params = opts.params;
  delete opts['params'];
  var R = spawn('phantomjs', params, opts);
  R.on('exit',function(code)
  {
    log('got exit code: '+code)

    done();
  })
}
```

You could also add some error handling there ie. but this might serve as a starting point.